# How to compile all drivers in the staging tree of the Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, drivers

I have downloaded the latest linux kernel and the Next tree, I want to run sparse on  'drivers/staging' tree, I tried enabling all the drivers via `make menuconfig` and then did

`make C=1 M=drivers/staging`

But the above command only builds some of the drivers, not all.

How do I enable more staging drivers to be built ?

Comment: Did you try `make allyesconfig`?

Comment: Yes, does that include all of the modules ?.. I just tried it out though, but still the same behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special symbol in the Kconfig files called `BROKEN`.  Code which doesn't work correctly at all (usually catastrophically fails) is marked in the Kconfig files with a dependency on this symbol, which is not defined anywhere by Kconfig itself, and therefore is not set by `allyesconfig` or any other automatic config targets.  A reasonable percentage of the drivers in the staging tree fall into this category, and thus `make allyesconfig` will not include many of them.  I'm not 100% certain, but I believe that you can manually add `BROKEN=y` at the end of the `.config` file in your build directory, then manually enable the Kconfig symbols either by adding them by hand in a similar manner to `BROKEN`, or through `make menuconfig`.  You may also need to enable the `COMPILE_TEST` symbol, but that one has an entry in the menuconfig UI (it's in the first sub-menu, near the top), and even then there is a possibility that some of the drivers may be architecture dependent.

Comment: I tried adding `BROKEN=y` as well as setting the `CONFIG_COMPILE_TEST` flag. The I ran a `make clean` then again `make C=1 M=drivers/staging`... Still the same

Comment: Even after setting those explicitly, you'll still need to enable the individual drivers.  Also, I forgot, the `BROKEN` symbol _might_ be `CONFIG_BROKEN` instead, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Ok... But How are Individual Drivers Enabled ? via `menuconfig` ?

Comment: I checked for `CONFIG_BROKEN`, there is no flag by that name.

Comment: Also I wanted to know that, it is not necessary to compile the whole kernel for compiling these drivers right ? Sorry if I sound silly

Comment: t shouldn't be necessary to _compile_ the whole kernel, although there will probably be some files generated outside of the staging directory, because there are a couple of headers that get dynamically generated by the build process.

Comment: Yes, there were files outside the staging directory that needed to be compiled.
`allyesconfig` did the trick, even without setting `BROKEN`
Thank You!